# What could be the cause of the error message "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.io.FileChannelUtil

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

whenever i try to build my android studio project it throw these errors

**Error 1**

```
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gpuv2:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':gpuv2:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
   > Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, G:\1 New apps\codecanyon-WMgBo0f2-video-maker-editor-photo-slideshow-allinone\videomaker\gpuv2\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\release\out)) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@7b2f9d5) before task ':gpuv2:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported`
```

**Error 2**
`java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.io.FileChannelUtil (in unnamed module @0x5876a9af) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x5876a9af`

***Error 3***

```
CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
```

i searched on google but didn't find any solution